# psql コマンドと sql コマンドの違いは？

Tags: linux, sql, postgresql

データベースの勉強を始めた初心者のものです。
唐突な質問で大変申し訳ないのですが、psqlコマンドとsqlコマンドは同じものなのでしょうか？ それとも違うものなのでしょうか？

参考にしたのはこちらのサイトです。

PostgreSQLコマンド

- [PostgreSQLをコマンドラインで操作する - @IT](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0010/19/news002.html)
- [PostgreSQLの使い方 - DBOnline](http://www.dbonline.jp/postgresql/)
- [PostgreSql コマンドの覚え書き](http://qiita.com/mm36/items/1801573a478cb2865242)

SQLコマンド

- [初めてSQLコマンドを叩く緊張と感動の一瞬 - @IT](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0702/21/news111.html)
- [SQLコマンド - PostgreSQL 9.2.4文書](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.2/html/sql-commands.html)
- `http://qiita.com/KENJU/items/313b5640da05834a53aa` (編注: リンク切れ)

Comment: psqlコマンドはPostgreSQLに付属するコマンドのことだと思いますが、「sqlコマンド」とは何を指す言葉なのでしょうか？どのサイトで使われていたとか、どんな使い方をするコマンドだとか、質問に追記していただけませんか？

Answer (score 2):

psqlコマンドは OS 上で実行する psql という名前のプログラムです。
psql を起動すると PostgreSQL に接続し 色々な操作ができます。

余談ですが、MySQL の場合は `mysql` 、SQL Server だと `sqlcmd.exe` `osql.exe` 、Oracle だと `sqlplus` というプログラムだったりします。

SQL コマンドは リレーショナルデータベース管理システム (RDBMS) 全般で使用できる データの操作や定義を 行うための データベース言語です。PostgreSQLに限らず様々なRDBMSで使用できるように標準化されています。また、RDBMS毎に拡張された 構文を持ちます。

代表的なSQLコマンド

- `SELECT ...` : 問い合わせクエリ
- `INSERT ...` : レコードの追加
- `UPDATE ...` : カラムの更新
- `DELETE ...` : レコード削除

実際の使い方は、OS 上で psql コマンドを実行して PostgreSQL に接続して、その上で SQL コマンドを使って データベースに対して問い合わせをするイメージです。

例 psql の起動＆PostgreSQL へ接続

```
$ psql -h localhost -U dbuser -d dbname
Password for user dbuser: ここでパスワード入力
```

例 psql 上で hoge テーブルに対して SQL コマンド (SELECT文) を実行。

```
dbname=> SELECT * FROM hoge;  ←ここでSQLを実行。「dbname=>」は psqlのプロンプト。
       id | city                ←ここから下がSQLの実行結果
----------+-------
        1 | tokyo 
        2 | osaka
        3 | sapporo
```

Comment: とても分かりやすく論理的に説明して頂きありがとうございました！
イメージが描けて情報整理をすることが出来ました。

Answer (score 1):

私の経験ではpostgresqlの場合、「psqlコマンド」と「SQLコマンド」と言うときは、次の使い分け方で言われることは（ときどき）あるように思います。他のDBは知らないので何とも言えません。

- psqlコマンド：シェルから実行できるコマンド名のこと。psqlと言う名前のコマンドラインツールのこと
- SQLコマンド：psqlをコマンドラインから実行した後に使われる、テーブルを作成したり削除したりすることのできる命令(コマンド)のこと

参考：
[psql (PostgreSQL 9.2.4文書)](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.2/html/app-psql.html)
[SQLコマンド (PostgreSQL 9.2.4文書)](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.2/html/sql-commands.html)